# Android Studio 3.3: New Gradle Sync is not supported due to containing Kotlin modules (invalid type code: 68)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

in a java-kotlin hybrid using Android Studio 3.3 and above, I get an *invalid type code: 68* error message. When using gradle 5.1 and above I get an additional message saying "*New Gradle Sync is not supported due to containing Kotlin modules*"

How to reproduce in android studio 3.3:

1) create a new android project in java with a blank activity

2) create a kotlin class file

3) click on the configure kotlin button to add the kotlin plugins and library to the project

4) sync gradle

My projects used to run fine on the previous Android Studio stable release (3.2.1)

full stack trace:

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.doFetchModels(SyncExecutor.java:255)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.executeFullSync(SyncExecutor.java:239)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.syncProject(SyncExecutor.java:197)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.lambda$syncProject$1(SyncExecutor.java:134)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:209)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.syncProject(SyncExecutor.java:139)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.sync(NewGradleSync.java:185)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.access$000(NewGradleSync.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync$2.run(NewGradleSync.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 68
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.throwFailure(ProviderConnection.java:205)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:193)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runClientAction(ProviderConnection.java:153)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:222)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParametrizedActionRunner.execute(ParametrizedActionRunner.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:54)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 68
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1563)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1919)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:74)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: I did the exact same steps, twice. It works. The first gradle sync it does do raise a warning but that's it. It compiles and runs fine. Kotlin 1.3.11, Gradle 4.10.1.. You're issue is * StreamCorruptedException*.

Comment: @shkschneider but what is corrupted then? When I use the same downloaded gradle wrapper (4.10.1) on android studio 3.2.1, it works.

Comment: What made you use Gradle 5.1? By default it sets up Gradle 4.10.1 when I create a new project.

Comment: @shkschneider I have tried every possible gradle version. None work with AS 3.3. I meant that gradle 4.10.1 for example works with AS 3.2.1 but doesn't work with AS 3.3. I mentioned gradle 5.1 because that gives an additional error message. gradle 5.1 does seem to work on a java only project or kotlin only project in AS 3.3.

Comment: I have the same issue in Android Studio 3.4 (kotlin 1.3.31 gradle 3.4.0 wrapper 5.1.1  )

Comment: same issue android studio 3.4

Comment: I was getting the same error in Android Studio 3.4 after creating my first project, but by the time I finished Googling, found this, looked into a fix on a couple other sites, and looked back to my project, it had fixed itself...  Might just need to finish downloading updates at this point.

Comment: rebuild after its build once ...

Comment: I experienced exactly the same as user681574; It fixed itself.

Comment: update: I am now able to build successfully using Android Studio 3.4.1 with the corresponding android gradle plugin (3.4.1) and Gradle 5.1.1.

Answer (score 26):

Change Preferences > Experimental > Only sync the active variant (uncheck this).

Alternatively, to edit the corresponding setting manually in your project files: Try setting not.eligible.for.single.variant.sync to true in .idea/workspace.xml

You can either edit the XML directly as shown below or use the Settings UI of IntelliJ:

```
  <component name="PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="not.eligible.for.single.variant.sync" value="true" />
  </component>
```

This is because single variant sync is not supported in Kotlin

> Note: This optimization fully supports projects that include Java and
>   C++ languages, and has some support for Kotlin. When enabling the
>   optimization for projects with Kotlin content, Gradle sync falls back
>   to using full variants internally.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#single_variant_sync

As to why Gradle is failing to fall back to full variant sync automatically, or why Android Studio isn't automatically setting this flag for you, I have no idea.

Comment: Just for information. In my case this property was true by default and issue appears

Comment: If you have a working project to reference, I recommend making a backup of your broken project and then replacing parts of it with the working project until the issue occurs. That's what I did. Narrowed it down to the .idea directory, then a specific file, then a specific property.